# C++ BASS Library - simple mp3 sample playing

Tags: c++, bass

I have checked the BASS reference for a solution, but it was not to be found by me. My audio just does not want to play and yes, I checked if my speakers are working. Here is the "code":

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "D:\\Libraries\BASS\c\bass.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{   
    BASS_Init(-1, 44100, 0, 0, NULL);
    BASS_SetVolume(1);
    HSAMPLE sample = BASS_SampleLoad(false, "1.mp3", 0, 0, 1, BASS_SAMPLE_MONO);
    HCHANNEL channel=BASS_SampleGetChannel(sample, FALSE); 
    BASS_ChannelPlay(channel, FALSE); 
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I tried really different initialization setting etc. Nothing seemed to be working. The '1.mp3' file is in the debug folder of my "app". Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check the result of each function call. If any fails, that should tell you what's going wrong.

Comment: BASS_Init returns 'true', so according to the reference it is working, however, it turns out that BASS_SampleLoad returns '0'. How is that, tho? Tried it with several mp3/wav files and was the same.

Comment: Checked it which BASS_ERROR flag it is on the BASS_SampleLoad call, and it says that it's the BASS_ERROR_FILEOPEN (can't open the file). Can't see why, tho. Reference says that it supports my file extension, and the music plays normally through another soft.

Comment: Perhaps wherever you've put the file isn't the working directory when the program runs. Try giving the full path.

Comment: It is not that. Went through it several times, changed the directory, wrote the full path, but the error remains unchanged.

Comment: is "BASS_ChannelPlay" supposed to return immediately, if so, can you see the threads BASS opened?  Where's your BASS shutdown code?  (Maybe after a reboot it's going to play?)
If "BASS_ChannelPlay" is not supposed to return immediately, your `system("pause");` is not necessary.

Comment: In what I understand it is supposed to return it as soon as u call it. The problem lies within the file reading part.

Comment: Tried out to CREATE a sample at a default frequency, and it does play normally with that code. I just don't know what to do to get the file loaded.

Answer (score -1):

Sample for playing must be of `void*` type. Try as I did:

```
//path to file 
string *filePath = new string("/home/user/Qt-Projects/bass/sample.mp3");
```

Function to reduct to type `void*`:

```
const void* getFile(string* file){
    return file->data();
}
```

And finish:

```
streamHandle = BASS_StreamCreateFile(false, getFile(filePath), 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: This is incorrect. The [documentation page](http://www.un4seen.com/doc/#bass/BASS_StreamCreateFile.html) shows you can use literal for file name `HSTREAM stream=BASS_StreamCreateFile(FALSE, "afile.mp3", 0, 0, 0);`

Comment: @KillzoneKid thank you I had been look for the docs page for a while